# Why does Lightroom disable chromatic abberation correction by default?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, chromatic-aberration, lightroom-5

Why is chromatic aberration correction disabled in Lightroom by default? In my opinion, it is the feature that has to be applied always. This is also what most (to my knowledge) built-in camera JPG converters do. I am not aware of any use case where keeping chromatic aberrations would be desired.

It is really annoying to scroll down to Lens Correction tab and enable chromatic aberration for every photo in the stream. Is it possible to enable this feature by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you want to apply it to all photos, the easiest method is to create a Preset which you then apply at import. To do so:

- Open any photo in the Develop module
- Enable Chromatic Aberration settings as desired
- In the left hand palette, click the + next to Presets
- Name your preset and ensure that only the CA correction settings are checked
- Click Create

When you import photos, on the right hand palette, click choose the appropriate Preset from the Develop Settings dropdown on the Apply During Import tab, et voilà, automatic CA correction. Just be aware that the setting will only apply to one lens, so if you use multiple lenses in a shoot, you want to avoid using the preset.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question in the title: Because not every photo has chromatic aberration, and therefore not everyone wants to enable the fix.

Also, since automatic defringing looks for fringe colors to remove, it may actually desaturate parts which are of this color but not fringed, even though this is not very likely. So you would need to go to the menu again to set fringe colors manually to fix this wrong defringing, which would be more frustrating than your case.

To answer how to do it for multiple photos at once:

- Enable it for one photo as you already do.
- In grid view, select all the photos, including the one you've modified.
- Right click > Develop > Sync settings
- Here only select the setting you want to sync, i.e. aberration fixing / defringin under lens corrections
- Hit enter

Comment: You can also set it as a Preset and then apply it during import.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall this i what I was looking for! A preset, thank you. If you formulate it as an answer, I will mark it.